# \tkzPointShowCoord not showing its xlabel

Tags: pgfplots, labels, axis, tkz-euclide, showlabels

I'm trying to plot a std normal distribution filled to a certain point `$z_\alpha$`, the problem is that \tkzPointShowCoord label doesn't appear in the plot, the following is the code i used:

```
\newcommand\gauss[2]{1/(sqrt(2*pi*#2))*exp(-((x-#1)^2)/(2*#2))} % normal random variable


\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.7]
\begin{axis}[every axis plot post/.append style={
  mark=none,domain=-3:3,samples=50,smooth, very thick}, 
axis x line*=bottom, % no box around the plot, only x and y axis
axis y line*=left, % the * suppresses the arrow tips
enlargelimits=upper, 
legend style={draw=none, nodes={scale =.8}, at={(1.7,1.2)}}, 
legend cell align={left}] % extend the axes a bit to the right and top
\addplot[smooth,blue, name path=f]{\gauss{0}{1}};
\path [name path=xaxis]
      (\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/xmin},0) --
      (\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/xmax},0);
\addplot[red!10, opacity=0.8] fill between [of=f and xaxis, soft clip={domain=-5:1}];
\tkzDefPoint(1,.2419){L}
\tkzPointShowCoord[noydraw=true, xlabel=$z_\alpha$](L)
\legend{$\mu =0~ \sigma^2 = 1$}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Thanks in advance for any help

Comment: You don't need `tkz-euclide` to do this. This package concerns Euclidean geometry. and with tkz-euclide 4 you can't do this. You need  to use `pgfplots` or perhaps` tikz`. I don't know how to use `pgfplots' but the problem here is to find the units used by 'pgfplots'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer in another post
[Hidden or Misplaced Node Labels when using Tikz Graphics Package](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/175947/hidden-or-misplaced-node-labels-when-using-tikz-graphics-package)

basically I had to add the label using `\node` and add `clip=false` in the style section.